# Install4j JVM arguments

Tags: install4j

I'm using Install4j 7.0.12.
Installation process finished well, but when I have tried to run uninstall, I'm getting error:
"The JVM could not be started. The maximum heap size (-Xmx) might be too large or an antivirus or firewall tool could block the execution."

I have disabled firewall and antivirus, but without any success. Is there any way how to specify maximum heap size when the installer/uninstaller is already build? What is default size of this java argument?

Comment: You can execute the uninstaller from the command line with the /create-i4j-log argument to get more information

Comment: Your hint helped very much. In the log I have found that subfolder /jre contains broken java. Thank you very much!